# Simple script issue?

Tags: html, forms

for some reason I cannot get any form to work correctly on my website, I even went to w3school and copied a simple test form to see if it works, and it does not, here it is:

**welcome.php:**

> ```
> <?
> Welcome <?php echo $_GET["fname"]; ?>!<br />
> You are <?php echo $_GET["age"]; ?> years old.
> ?>
> ```

**form:**

> ```
> <form action="welcome.php" method="get">
> Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
> Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
> <input type="submit" />
> </form>
> ```

I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I tried with and without brackets, and still I get a blank page, in explorer I get a 500 Error, most likely causes is maintenance or Programming Error", but I had the same issue last night so I doubt its maintenance, and everything else works.

Comment: PS: both the script and form have the same method, the type was because I was trying them both, anyways, I tried both GET and POST, same blank page.

Comment: have you gotten any php-page working?

Comment: Yes, for some reason I have another script with a GET command that is passed through a link to work, so I have no idea why this is not working, there is nothing special here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the beginning `<?` and ending `?>` from your welcome.php.

Comment: Oops, I even copied that to my answer - still didn't notice it. +1

Comment: LOL yes, I realized that later last night from copying the script over, and it was driving me nuts. I hate it when that happens.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Your form uses `get` and you're reading from `$_POST`.

Either change html to

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
```

or change the php to

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_GET["age"]; ?> years old.
```

Also, make sure the value is present using the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
Welcome <?php echo isset($_GET["fname"]) ? $_GET["fname"] : "Guest"; ?>!<br />
```

Comment: No that was a typo when I put the question here, I was doing some testing.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$_POST["fname"]` you should also specify post as method in your form

welcome.php:

```
<?
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
?>
```

form:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```